# Manual carousel with all aligned images

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap carousel but he is automatic and manual. I wanted to change him in order to use it only manually and I want to separate the items with spaces.

This is my carousel html :

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style=" width:608px; height: 420px !important;">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="./assets/image/Meduse-aurelie.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="./assets/image/Merou-lanceole.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="./assets/image/Iguane.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="./assets/image/requin-marcheur.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

And this is my carousel css :

```
.carousel-item {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I have this result :

[image: carousel with not aligned images]

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I want to see all my images as stripe. And I want to slide the images only manually thanks to arrows.

Comment: `.carousel-inner { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: I tried it but it does'nt work

Comment: Hmm ok, can you try to recreate your issue using JSFiddle or something?